# How can I upload a pdf file to MySql?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code done and it woks but I can't upload a pdf file. How can I do it?

```
    if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"]))
{
    if ($_FILES["userfile"]["type"]=="image/jpeg" || $_FILES["userfile"]["type"]=="image/pjpeg" || $_FILES["userfile"]["type"]=="image/gif" || $_FILES["userfile"]["type"]=="image/bmp" || $_FILES["userfile"]["type"]=="image/png" || $_FILES["userfile"]["type"]=="image/pdf")
    {
        $info=getimagesize($_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"]);

        $imagenEscapes=mysqli_real_escape_string($link, file_get_contents($_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"]));

        $sql="INSERT INTO `imagephp` (anchura,altura,tipo,imagen) VALUES (".$info[0].",".$info[1].",'".$_FILES["userfile"]["type"]."','".$imagenEscapes."')";
        $result=mysqli_query($link,$sql);

        # Cogemos el identificador con que se ha guardado
        $id=mysqli_insert_id($link);

        echo "<div class='mensaje'>Imagen agregada con el id ".$id."</div>";
    }else{
        echo "<div class='error'>Error: El formato de archivo tiene que ser JPG, GIF, BMP o PNG.</div>";
    }
}
```

Comment: use application/pdf

Comment: your code uploads images only... as @devodedra have indicated please implement as per his suggession.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use $_FILES["userfile"]["type"] == "application/pdf"

Answer (score 0):

You are trying detect PDF file using `image/pdf`. That should be `application/pdf`. There are no `MIME` type as `image/pdf`.

So correct if statement is,

```
if ($_FILES["userfile"]["type"]=="application/pdf" || $_FILES["userfile"]["type"]=="image/jpeg" || $_FILES["userfile"]["type"]=="image/pjpeg" || $_FILES["userfile"]["type"]=="image/gif" || $_FILES["userfile"]["type"]=="image/bmp" || $_FILES["userfile"]["type"]=="image/png")
{

}
```